# Josephus prob using arrays?

Tags: c++, josephus

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem
The user can choose how many people are in the circle.
The user can choose the value of each person.
The user can choose the counting number for the persons death.
ex. User picks 5, every 5th person shall die.

I was thinking something like - 
User choose amount of people ex- 50
PeopleArray becomes PeopleArray[50]

User chooses value of elements in PeopleArray[50]
They would have to type 50 values for the 50 elements

Death
User picks 3 so every third person dies how would I erase that number from the array.

Problem ^-Not sure on how to do the above with arrays

```
    int main(){
    int people = 5;
    int peopleArray[5];
    int peopleValue = 1;
    int death;

    cout << "Enter the amount of people: ";
    cin >> people;

    peopleArray[people];        

    for(int x = 1;x<=people;x++){
        cout << "Enter the value of person #" << x << ":";
        cin>> peopleValue;
        peopleArray[peopleValue]; //Suppose to put the value into the array

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: I don't know if it's even possible for the user to insert the # of elements and values of an array and how would I erase a certain element in the array

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clearer. Your comment indicates that your actual problems has nothing to to with the details of the Josephus problem, but is much more basic, like "How to store/mainpulate data in C++. (Something like this, but **much** more precise please!)

Comment: @SKTT1Faker You can't "erase" a value of an array from what I know. You can certainly call it, and set to a value like 0. And you can certainly insert the # of elements and values of an array (sounds like multi-dimensional arrays to me) But IMO your question is seriously confusing, even with your comment

Comment: Arrays are not very good for random inserts and removes, as you'll have to shift all remaining elements each time.  A liked list would be much more appropriate here.  That said, I agree with the other commentators that your question is mostly unclear.

Comment: Yeah, I saw other people using linked list but I'm not too sure how to use it or explain it so it'll look like I just copy and pasted. I thought the question was clear but I guess it's how the person sees it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly what you are trying to do would be something like...

```
vector<int> totalPeople;
int totalIn;
int deathIn;
int person = 1;
int nthPerson = 0;

cout << "Enter total number of people." << endl;
cin >> totalIn;
cout << endl << "Pick the nth person." << endl;
cin >> deathIn;

for ( int i = 0; i < totalIn; i++ )
{
  totalPeople.pushback(person++);
}
nthPerson = deathIn - 1;
while ( nthPerson < totalPeople.size() )
{
  totalPeople.erase(totalPeople.begin() + nthPerson);
  nthPerson = nthPerson + (deathIn -1);
}
```

or say that totalPeople[nthPerson] = 0;
This will remove the nth person from the total list of people.